# Will AngularFirestore with Native Firebase API Work On Native Platforms?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4, angularfire

So while converting the functions in an app I'm working on to work with AngularFire instead of Firebase's web SDK's, I noticed that you can call the firestore property of AngularFirestore and it allows you to use Firebase's native API.

For example:

```js
import { AngularFirestore, DocumentReference, DocumentSnapshot, QueryDocumentSnapshot } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
...
constructor(private dataService: DataService, private db: AngularFirestore
    ) { }
...

listenImages(): Function { //I call db.firestore here
        return this.db.firestore.collection('users').doc('bisonlife').collection('bisonlife').doc(this.dataService.uid.value)
            .collection('images').orderBy("dateAdded", "desc").onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
                let messages = [];
                querySnapshot.forEach(thing => {
                    messages.push({
                        ...thing.data()
                    });
                });
                this.zone.run(() => {
                    this.uploadedPhotos = messages;
                });
            });
    }
```

Throws no errors. Even though it uses Firebase's native API instead of AngularFirestore, it still runs on a regular browser.

I'm currently using Ionic. My question is that if I call Firebase's native API in this way, will AngularFire still be able to wrap the functions into native code if I build to iOS and Android? It will definitely save me a lot of time if that were the case. I made the mistake of using the Web SDK for an app I want to put on mobile devices, so I'm currently trying to convert all of my Firestore-dependent functions into something AngularFirestore can use. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`AngularFire` doesn't call any native code. It's just an npm package which actually uses the Firebase web sdk to interact with firebase.

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/src/auth/auth.ts#L5

When you download a plugin example :

```
cordova plugin add <cordova-plugin>
```

Then that plugin will be calling native code. But this is not the case. You shouldn't have any issue with using firebase web sdk in ionic. Already `angularfire` is using it in its source code.

The whole point of using `angularfire` is to make it easier in binding data to the template.. So its better to use it in an ionic project that uses angular.(but that has nothing to do with native code calling..)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have no idea why I was having such a hard time! Maybe it was because of a login issue? I'm not really sure. I am trying to import AngularFirestore in everywhere it requires Firebase though haha. Do you want to see my original source code and maybe you can figure out why it's acting bonkers?